# NoSuchElementException with unknown cause using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

While writing selenium testcases for a webapplication I'm having trouble with the xpath selector. The element of the HTML-code which should be clicked on by Selenium is the following:

```
<a title="Voeg een vak toe" href="#" onclick="javascript:$.colorbox({width:818,href:'/olo-cleanjump/profiel/addVakForm'}); return false;">
  <p class="add">
    <img class="add-icon" src="/olo-cleanjump/static/images/icon_add.png"/>
    Voeg vak toe
  </p>
</a>
```

The Selenium IDE plugin for firefox gives me the following selenium code for this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.add")).click();
```

The addVakForm javascript function that is called by this link opens a colorbox with the following HTML (I shortened it, there are around 30 similar div's with class "lesboek_popup") inside:

```
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="display: block; width: 776px; overflow: auto; height: 653px;">
  <div id="profielpagina_add">
    <h2>Voeg een vak toe aan je profiel</h2>
    <div class="lesboek_popup">
      <a class="content" href="/olo-cleanjump/profiel/addvak/120776">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </a>
      <p class="caption">
        <a href="/olo-cleanjump/profiel/addvak/120776">Engels</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="lesboek_popup">
      <a class="content" href="/olo-cleanjump/profiel/addvak/120786">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </a>
      <p class="caption">
        <a href="/olo-cleanjump/profiel/addvak/120786">Biologie</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

For the test I want to open the 'Biologie' link. Selenium IDE got me the following selenium code to do this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='profielpagina_add']/div[20]/a")).click();
```

to select this biology link element.
Based on this I wrote the following testcase:

```
 Test
public void testAddRemoveVak() throws Exception {
    this.get("");

    // vak 1 toevoegen
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.add")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='profielpagina_add']/div[20]/a")).click();

    // vak 2 toevoegen
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.add")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='profielpagina_add']/div[20]/a")).click();

    assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='vak']")).size(), 2);

    // vak 2 verwijderen
    this.get("profiel/removevak/120791");

    assertEquals(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='vak']")).size(), 1);
}
```

The part

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.add")).click();
```

actually was successful, so after this call the colorbox should be loaded. However the

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='profielpagina_add']/div[20]/a")).click();
```

causes an NoSuchElementException, while this element definitely is present in the colorbox when I check for myself (the call/xpath was even autogenerated by Selenium IDE). Does anyone have a clue what may cause the NoSuchElementException?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you should wait when your popup appears. Try to use [Implicit waits](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits)

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Also instead of xpath you can use `driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Biologie")).click()` if it the only link with text Biologie on your page

Comment: Good thinking, I added a ImplicitlyWait of up to 10 seconds. It did not solve my problem yet though. I found out that the complete colorbox div was not locatable by Selenium. At pageload this div is hidden offcourse, but the driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.add")).click(); call should 'unhide' the colorbox div. This make take a while, but the the way I understood it the ImplicitlyWait setting gives this element up to 10 seconds to appear in the DOM. Does anyone know what may cause the colorbox div (and it's sub-elements) not to be locatable by Selenium?

Comment: Is it possible, that there are two divs with equal ids `profielpagina_add`? Also you can always check if your colorbox located correct with Firebug and selenium IDE. If it not, then the problem is that you use incorrect locator. Otherwise you can increase waiting time to e.g 20 seconds, or if it the only slow part of your tests use Explicit wait

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There is only one div with the id 'profielpagina_add'. The problem is that this div is within a div with id 'colorbox', and this whole 'colorbox' div is not found by Selenium when I test for its presence. I tried using an explicit wait of 20 seconds (or even 40 seconds) after clicking the link that opens the colorbox before testing for presence of a div with id 'colorbox', but this results in a timeout of the explicit wait. When I click the link that opens the colorbox outside Selenium, it opens almost instantly, so the time shouldn't be the cause. Any more ideas maybe?

Comment: @NiekTax, open Selenium IDE, invoke your colorbox, type `id=colorbox` in target field in Selenium IDE, click Find button. What do you see? If log shows `[error] locator not found: id=colorbox`, then I assume that your colorbox opened in new window which you have to select with `selectWindow` command

Comment: @NiekTax, or if your colorbox is opened in iframe, you should switch to this iframe first `driver.switchTo().frame("frameName");`

Comment: I solved the problem. The cause was the Selenium HTMLDriver that was used instead of a FirefoxDriver. This HTMLDriver only has basic javascript support and could not handle JQuery colorbox calls. Anyway, thanks for your help Aleh Douhi!